# Accessing class attribute without leading underscore in variable name

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

I understand that single leading underscores in variable names have no meaning to the interpreter (except when importing using *), therefore I'm quite confused by the following problem that I'm encountering while trying to understand somebody else's code:

I have a class called *Configuration* and a class called *Interface*.

*Configuration* has an attribute called *_chooser* (with one leading underscore) that usually contains another object.

```
class Configuration(object):
    def __init__(self):
         self._chooser = AnotherObj()
```

Via some other function, an instance of *Configuration* (let's call it *ConfigObj*) is given to a new instance of *Interface* (let's call it *InterfaceObj*). *ConfigObj* is also stored as an attribute of the new *InterfaceObj* object.

```
class Interface(object)
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config

    def aFunction(self)
        print(self.config.chooser)


def someOtherFunction()
    ConfigObj = Configuration()
    InterfaceObj = Interface(ConfigObj)
```

Now, a function of *InterfaceObj* accesses the variable ***self.config.chooser*** (without the underscore!), even tough I never defined it.
The variable *chooser* also doesn't show in autocomplete (*_chooser* does), neither does it show using

```
dir(self.config)
```

or

```
vars(self.config)
```

(both called right before the questionable call of *self.config.chooser* in *aFunction*)

Keep in mind that the above code snippets are a boiled down version of the entire actual code. I looked through everything but could not figure out, where the variable without the underscore came from or why it isn't visible. 
I was also unable to replicate this in a separate environment and any other variables I define myself do have to be called with the underscore, otherwise they simply return *None*.

What magic could be going on here?
Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: This simply shouldn’t work. There could be any number of things in the full code doing “the magic”…

Comment: "I was also unable to replicate this in a separate environment" - suggests maybe you have some old code or .pyc files in this environment?  "otherwise they simply return None" - I'd expect an `AttributeError` to be raised for accesses to undefined attributes, unless there's some `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` magic involved.

Comment: There is a __getattr__(self, key) in the Configuration object! Does this get called when I use config.something? because there's something built in there that calls _chooser.
I'm quite new to Python, so I didn't know what that was about ...

This is actually the answer to my problem, thanks!!

Comment: [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__), if implemented, is called when a non-existent instance attribute is accessed.  It can be customised to do anything, but it's not uncommon to have it return some kind of default value.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the tip!